# What happens to my data if I cancel my iCloud Storage subscription?

Tags: ios, icloud, storage

I have a plan of $0.99/month. Now I want to cancel my subscription.

I have 30GB of iCloud Data. I don't know what happen with all my data in iCloud. Will I still be able to get access, or it will be deleted once I cancel my subscription?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this Apple iCloud Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203527):

> If you downgrade your storage plan and your content exceeds the storage you have available, new photos and videos won't upload to iCloud Photo Library and your devices will stop backing up to iCloud.
>
> iCloud Drive and iCloud-enabled apps won’t update across your devices, and you won't be able to send or receive messages with your iCloud email address.
>
> To use iCloud after exceeding your available storage, remove backups, photos, documents, or email messages you don’t need. You can access photos, videos, and documents for 30 days after you delete or disable iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Drive.

Answer (score 4):

This is the message Apple emailed when my 50 GB storage was cancelled.

> You have used up all of your 5 GB of free iCloud storage.
>
> All the photos, videos and documents that are currently in iCloud will still be stored safely, but any new ones will not be saved to there. Soon, you will not be able to send or receive emails with your iCloud email address….

Answer (score 0):

Apple removed all my files from iCloud Drive after my subscription was canceled by them as no payments (no valid card). It's madness. It's Apple.

As far as I know if you cancel subscription plan it's different from when they cancel it. my files disappeared on iCloud after approx. 3 months. To be clear - all files.